# "Cette affaire l'est pour une autre raison." - what's that "l" there supposed to mean?

Tags: grammaire, pronoms-personnels

This is a short dialogue from a podcast for students of French. It's just two people talking:

> Wal-Mart est le plus grand employeur dans le secteur privé aux États-Unis. Cette entreprise emploie plus de 1,4 millions de personnes aux États-Unis. Elle possède 8500 magasins dans 15 pays.
>
> Oh, cette affaire est extrêmement importante. Potentiellement, l'obligation d'indemnisation pourrait atteindre des milliards de dollars.
>
> C'est juste ! Mais en plus, elle n'implique pas seulement Wal-Mart. Cette affaire, « extrêmement importante », comme tu dis, **l'est** pour une autre raison. La défaite de Wal-Wart pourrait rendre n'importe quelle grande société vulnérable à des allégations similaires.

Why is there an **l** before **est**? Is it the pronoun **le**? Why do we need it there? That's something I really don't understand.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

The "l'" is indeed the elided form of "le". It is a pronoun that replaces "extrêmement important".

Let us imagine the sentence without this pronoun:

> Cette affaire, extrêmement importante, est extrêmement importante pour une autre raison.

Repeating "extrêmement importante" is awkward and should be avoided. Hence, it is replaced by a pronoun.

A similar example:

> Sa voiture est-elle grande ? Oui, elle l'est (= elle est grande)

Comment: Are you saying that the pronouns *le* and *elle* can refer to and replace adjectives in French? That's interesting. I'd like to know more about that.

Comment: Yes, but I can think only of "le" (or the elided l') to replace an attribute adjective, ie after a verb like "être", "sembler", etc. - whatever the gender and number (ex: Ces voitures sont grandes => ces voitures le sont). Let me see if I find a more  comprehensive reference on that.

Comment: See here (I just think the explanation does not stress enough that only attribute adjectives can be replaced by "le", ie adjectives used after *être*, *devenir*, etc.) https://french.kwiziq.com/revision/grammar/pronoun-le-can-also-replace-adjectives

Comment: Agree "le" is replacing "extrêmement importante", to avoid repetition. Upvoted. Should be chosen as the accepted answer.

Comment: Are you saying that the pronouns le and elle can refer to and replace adjectives in French?" It's "le", not "elle", "le" the neutral impersonal pronoun, and it can replace anything, any part of the sentence you don't want to repeat (absolutely not "the adjective part", the part with the repeated & important info). Cette fille est belle, et elle l'est parce qu'elle mange sainement, you could say literally "she is it/like this, because..." It replaces the whole sentence "Cette fille est belle

Comment: If you didn't replace it, you would say, with repetitions: Cette fille est belle. Et cette fille est belle parce que... Another mean is to say: Cette fille est belle, et si elle est belle c'est que..

Comment: "le" has no link with "elle". Elle is a personal pronoun, "le" is an impersonal pronoun.

Comment: @Quidam So, can I translate **Cette affaire, « extrêmement importante
», comme tu dis, l'est pour une autre raison.** like this: **This case, "extremely important", as you say, is like this for another reason.**?

Comment: Yes!...........

Comment: Note that there's maybe a little irony in the "comme tu dis", I don't know if it is shown with the "as you say" in English.